# Directive to change capital letters in Angular 14

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-directive

I have a template:

```
<div *ngFor="let article of articles">
  <h2>{{ article.title }}</h2>  
  <p>{{ article.authorName }}</p>
</div>
```

And i have a dataModel.ts file:

```
export interface IArticle {
  id: number
  title?: string
  authorName?: string}
```

How to write a directive that receives a string in the form of a name and checks whether the letters at the beginning of the surname and first name are capitalized, if not, then makes them large? Those:
artur haiduk -> Artur Haiduk

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/TitleCasePipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use angular predefined pipe [titlecase](https://angular.io/api/common/TitleCasePipe)

```html
   <div *ngFor="let article of articles">
         <h2>{{ article.title | titlecase }}</h2>  
         <p>{{ article.authorName | titlecase }}</p>
  </div>
```